# irregular shape background - css

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am using [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) to make a `Triangle Top Left` like so:

```
#triangle-topleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

output: [image]

but how can I make an irregular shape similar to this but cut out a corner on the bottom right?
ex:[image]

the html is straight forward : `<div id='triangle-topleft'><div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a gradient to fill up background with a transparent part.

```css
.Ttrgle {
  display:inline-block; /* or whatever or absolute position that allows to size it */
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 33%, red 33%);
  }
html {
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, gray,white,blue,purple,yellow,green,lime,pink,turquoise)
    }
```

```html
<span class="Ttrgle"></span>
```

Comment: thank you,  can you explain a little how this works please `background:linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 33%, red 33%);`

Comment: Nice solution, like it

Comment: @tq when you set the same value to gradient colors , they just start sharp from one to another, there is no fadding at all. the first value tells where to start and where to end , then each colors are taken one after each others , here only two. we start with transparent till 33%, then pickup next at 33% wich is red till 100%

Answer (score 4):

You could use a linear gradient

```css
body {
  background: #bada55;
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, red 60%, transparent 60%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: can you explain how this works please `background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, red 60%, transparent 60%);`

Comment: it's just saying that the place that the red stops is the same place in the gradient that the transparent starts - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient. =

Answer (score 3):

You can wrote something like this:

```css
#triangle-topleft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
}

.outer-div {position:relative;width:80px;height:80px;overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
 <div class="outer-div">
    <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a rotated pseudo element. The approach is similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work/24808936#24808936) but the transform origin is changed to `15% 100%` :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/coc8yqmo/2/)**

```css
div{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0; bottom:0;
    width:200%; height:200%;
    transform-origin: 15% 100%;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    background:red;
}

/* FOR THE DEMO */

body{background:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-8.jpg');background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Transforms are supported by [IE9 and over](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

*Note that I didn't include the vendor prefixes in the snippet. They are included in the fiddle demo.*

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the div in another div that is slightly smaller and overflow: hidden

```css
#triangle-topleft {
 border-top: 120px solid red;
 border-right: 120px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
#container {
    position:absolute;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='triangle-topleft'></div>
</div>
```